# Unable to access containerised version of Charles proxy web interface

Tags: docker, charles-proxy

I'm trying to containerize Charles web proxy. I'm using the Charles Proxy image shown here -> https://hub.docker.com/r/kurron/docker-charles-proxy/tags . When I:

- Fire up docker
- Create a container from the above image by executing the following:
  docker run -d -p 8890:8888 --name [CONTAINER_NAME]] kurron/docker-charles-proxy
- Open a browser and try to access the Charles web proxy web interface within the container by entering "http://localhost.charlesproxy.com:8890/"

I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this? Whats strange is if i proxy a mobile phone to the machine that's running the docker container and type http://control.charles/ into the mobile phones browser i can access the web interface but not able to access it on the machine thats running the container.

I've also tried using the suggestion mentioned below but get same issue:

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/

Answer (score 0):

The image you're trying to run hasn't been updated in [four years](https://hub.docker.com/r/kurron/docker-charles-proxy/tags). You might want to find something more supported (or build your own).

---

You can't just `docker run` that image. Charles is a GUI program, and needs to be able to bring up an interface on your local system, which requires access to your X windows server. If you read [the documentation associated with the image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kurron/docker-charles-proxy), it says, among other things:

> ### Launching The Image
>
> docker-compose up will launch the image allowing you to begin working on projects. The Docker Compose file is configured to mount your home directory into the container.

Looking at the [`docker-compose.yaml` file in the repository](https://github.com/kurron/docker-charles-proxy/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), we see:

```
version: '2'
services:
    charles:
        build: .
        image: charles:compose
        container_name: "charles"
        network_mode: "host"
        volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
        - /home/vagrant:/home/developer
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        user: 1000:1000
        environment:
            DISPLAY: unix:0.0
```

There are some problems there, but the basic idea is:

- Run the image using your UID
- Mount your home directory into the container (note that any writable directory will do; it doesn't actually require access to your home directory)
- Mount your X11 socket into the container
- Set the `DISPLAY` environment variable correctly

I was able to run it like this:

```
docker run -u $UID --net=host \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  -v $HOME/charles:/home/developer \
  -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
  kurron/docker-charles-proxy
```

This will place files generated by Charles inside `~/charles/` (where you'll find `.charles_config`, a `.charles` directory, and maybe a `.java` directory).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @larsks , docker is being hosted on MAC OSX 12.4 and from what i understand MAC OSX doesn't come with the x11 libraries. I installed the x11 libraries on my MAC from https://www.xquartz.org/ , ran the command that you provided in your answer in terminal but get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'unix/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.nZ6CTsewUL/org.xquartz:0' as the value of the DISP`

Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: The X11 environment under MacOS differs from what we see in Linux, and I don't have a Mac on which to test. You could try replacing `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` with `-v /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.nZ6CTsewUL/org.xquartz:0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, and then setting `-e DISPLAY=unix:0`.

Comment: When making the changes suggested in previous comment and running the following command `docker run -u $UID --net=host -v /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.nZ6CTsewUL/org.xquartz:0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 -v $HOME/charles:/home/developer -e DISPLAY=unix:0 kurron/docker-charles-proxy` it comes back with the following error -> `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0.` . Whats odd is i'm unable to find the whole folder directory for xquartz that dockers trying to map to; i can navigate to private/tmp but can't see com.apple.launchd.nZ6CTsewUL/org.xquartz:0 .

Comment: I'll need to see if I can get access to a Mac this evening to see if I can figure out a solution.

Comment: did you manage to look into this?